# INSERT INTO @Temp_Table VALUES from multi value SSRS Parameter

Tags: sql, reporting-services, report, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

i'm building a report using ssrs report builder where in the code there is a part where i have to insert into a temp table some values. these values should be loaded from a multi value parameter DatabaseName.
i tried the below code:

```
DECLARE @Rep_Temp TABLE(SurrogateKeyIDENTITY int not null IDENTITY (1,1),tempDBName nvarchar(100) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO @Rep_Temp (tempDBName) VALUES (@DatabaseName);
```

it works only if i select one value, when i select multiple value it will give error.

i also tried the below code with no success:

```
INSERT INTO @Rep_Temp (tempDBName) VALUES (join(Parameters!DatabaseName.Value,","));
```

appreciate your assistance.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it as per the below:

1. I added Parameter in the dataset: `@DBNameString  = join(Parameters!DatabaseName.Value,",")`
2. I tried to use STRING_SPLIT when inserting the table but i couldn't due to the fact that i have SQL Server 2012 "is not a recognized built-in function name". instead i did the following:

DECLARE @Rep_Temp TABLE(SurrogateKeyIDENTITY int not null IDENTITY (1,1),tempDBName     nvarchar(100) NOT NULL);

```
DECLARE @DBs VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @DBName VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @charSpliter CHAR;

SET @charSpliter = ','
SET @DBs = @DBNameString + @charSpliter;

WHILE CHARINDEX(@charSpliter, @DBs) > 0
BEGIN
SET @DBName = SUBSTRING(@DBs, 0, CHARINDEX(@charSpliter, @DBs))
SET @DBs = SUBSTRING(@DBs, CHARINDEX(@charSpliter, @DBs) + 1, LEN(@DBs))

INSERT INTO @Rep_Temp (tempDBName) VALUES (@DBName);    
END
```

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you try this solution? 
[Turning a multi-value parameter into a temp table in SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40534211/turning-a-multi-value-parameter-into-a-temp-table-in-sql-server-business-intelli)

Comment: i tried it, i got error  Invalid Object name 'dbo.splitstring', in the example they are using visual studio while i am using report builder 3.0, can you kindly advise the correct syntax?

Comment: DECLARE `@dbname NVARCHAR(100)
SET @dbname = 'DB1,DB2,DB3'
DECLARE `@Rep_Temp TABLE(SurrogateKeyIDENTITY int not null IDENTITY (1,1),tempDBName nvarchar(100) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO `@Rep_Temp (tempDBName) select(@dbname) this inserts multiple values into temp table

Comment: I also suggest to try this solution. Maybe you can use =join(Parameters!<your param name>.Value,",")
In your query, you can then reference the value like so:

where yourColumn in (@<your paramname>)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512105/passing-multiple-values-for-a-single-parameter-in-reporting-services

Comment: @ Atahan Ceylan, it will work only when @dbname contain one value example set @dbname='DB1', if i put multiple value i get error Incorrect syntax near ','